# search an array with one parameter-Java

Tags: java

I have a class gerbil and I've created an array of it's instance with proper initialization in the main method. Now I want to have a search function which will take only one parameter (basically the search string). How will I pass the gerbil array in the search function without passing it as a parameter.

```
public class Gerbil {
    String lab_id;
    String name;
    boolean isBite;
    public int[] eat;

    public Gerbil(int x) {
        eat = new int[x];
    }

    public String getLab_id() {
        return lab_id;
    }

    public void setLab_id(String lab_id) {
        this.lab_id = lab_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isBite() {
        return isBite;
    }

    public void setBite(boolean isBite) {
        this.isBite = isBite;
    }

    public void setEat(int a, int b) {
        eat[a]=b;
    }

    public int getEat(int a){
        return eat[a];
    }
```

declaration of the gerbil class array in the main method

```
Gerbil[] gerbils = new Gerbil[gerbil_no];

// initializing the Food class into the Gerbil Class

for (int x = 0; x < gerbils.length; x++) {
    gerbils[x] = new Gerbil(types);
}
```

Comment: make it a global variable, have you tried that..?

Comment: I tried to declare it on the main Class that have the main method, but i got some static related error

Comment: you just need to add static modifier for that global variable.. since you are using it in a static main function indeed..
something like: `private static Gerbil[] gerbils = new Gerbil[gerbil_no];`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you said, can you write 3-4 lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main class:

```
private static Gerbil[] gerbils;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initializing the Food class into the Gerbil Class
    gerbils =  = new Gerbil[gerbil_no];

    for (int x = 0; x < gerbils.length; x++) {
        gerbils[x] = new Gerbil(types);
    }
}
```

because you are using the variable in a static main function, you have to use a static modifier in the variable declaration indeed..

Comment: okay, i'm trying it, if that works for me definitely i'd mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to declare the array in the class scope (outside all functions):

```
private static Gerbil[] gerbils;
```

Now, initialize it with size in your main function:

```
gerbils = new Gerbil[gerbil_no];
```

So, finally, your class could look like this:

```
public class Gerbil 
{
    private static Gerbil[] gerbils;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // write code here to read the array size into gerbil_no

        // then initialize your array with size here
        gerbils =  = new Gerbil[gerbil_no];

        for (int x = 0; x < gerbils.length; x++) {
            gerbils[x] = new Gerbil(types);
        }
        // continue with your code
    }
}
```

**Note:** In Java, static functions can access only static members. Since main function (in Java) is static, you have to declare your array as static. You can read more about this here: http://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java

Comment: the gerbil_no comes from an user input.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in another class:

```
class Gerbil {
    String lab_id;
    String name;
    boolean isBite;
    public int[] eat;

    public Gerbil(int x) {
        eat = new int[x];
    }

    public String getLab_id() {
        return lab_id;
    }

    public void setLab_id(String lab_id) {
        this.lab_id = lab_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isBite() {
        return isBite;
    }

    public void setBite(boolean isBite) {
        this.isBite = isBite;
    }

    public void setEat(int a, int b) {
        eat[a]=b;
    }

    public int getEat(int a){
        return eat[a];
    }
}

class Y {
     private static final int gerbil_no = 0;
     Gerbil[] gerbils = new Gerbil[gerbil_no];
    void foo() {
        // initializing the Food class into the Gerbil Class
        for (int x = 0; x < gerbils.length; x++) {
            gerbils[x] = new Gerbil(10  /* You had types here */);
            gerbils[x].setName("Hello");
        }
    }
    Boolean search (String str) {
        for (int i = 0, length = gerbils.length; i < length; i++)
            if (gerbils[i].name.compareTo(str) == 0)
                return true; 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that required?